# menu item within the menu android

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I created a nested menu menus.xml, that when you do a touch to the item that has "@ drawable / menu" menu is displayed inside it, the idea is to do that by code, thanks.

I want to make the menu. xml by java code, any idea?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
android:icon="@drawable/menu"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    <menu>      
        <item
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:title="VIVO"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"    
            android:icon="@drawable/vivoon"
        />
        <item
            android:title="VOD"
            android:id="@+id/computer"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"    
            android:icon="@drawable/vodon"
        />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting code. However, what exactly is the question? Does anything work/not work?

Comment: and updated it, I do that by code in java

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since I'm still not completely sure what you want, I think you should check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) I believe this is what you are going for. If not, be a little more specific about what is or isn't working or about what you want.

Comment: The thing is, it works fine when I do it through layouts: I get a pull-down menu with the items I need. The issue is that this needs to be dynamic, and I can't do that with layouts, I need to do it in code since it depends on an external JSON. However, when I try to do it in Java, I get a different kind of menu.

Comment: onPrepareOptionsMenu() Look **[here]**(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) and see if that's what you are talking about. Put the code in there that will add/delete items